# Derivative of matrix by vector

Tags: matrices, partial-derivative, matrix-calculus

Consider a matrix $A(x)\in \mathbb{R}^{m,p}$, where $x\in \mathbb{R}^{n}$. The partial derivative of $A(x)$ by $x$ results in an $m$ x $pn$ matrix and thus, $\frac{\partial A(x)}{\partial x} \in \mathbb{R}^{m,pn}$. This is proven in the following [paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/287565444_Partial_derivative_of_matrix_functions_with_respect_to_a_vector_variable) where numerical layout was used. The paper also proves the following result $$\frac{\partial }{\partial x} (A(x)B(x))=\frac{\partial A(x)}{\partial x}(B(x)\otimes I_n) + A(x) \frac{\partial B(x)}{\partial x}$$

where $I_n$ is the identity matrix of size $n$. Following the derivation on the paper, I confirmed that if we had a vector $b\in\mathbb{R}^{p}$, the following is also true $$\frac{\partial }{\partial x} (A(x)b)=\frac{\partial A(x)}{\partial x}(b\otimes I_n) $$

Now I am trying to use this result but I'm getting the wrong matrix size. Here is my problem. Let $X=diag(x) \in \mathbb{R}^{n,n}$, $A(x) = GX$, where $G\in\mathbb{R}^{n,n}$ and size $p=n$, ie, now $b\in\mathbb{R}^n$. The following derivative result should be true $$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(A(x)b)=\frac{\partial (GX)}{\partial x}(b\otimes I_n)$$ where $(b\otimes I_n)\in\mathbb{R}^{n^2,n}$
Now the issue is that of taking the partial derivative of $GX$ w.r.t $x$. So far I tried the following, $$\frac{\partial}{\partial X}(GX) = \frac{\partial}{\partial vecX}(I_n \otimes G)vec(X) = (I_n \otimes G)$$ and knowing that my matrix $X$ is a diagonal matrix, I would have changed the kronecker product to a Khatri-Rao product resulting in $(I_n\odot G)\in\mathbb{R}^{n^2,n}$ (though I'm not sure about this step). The issue remains that if I try to joint the resulting terms, the product $(I_n\odot G)(b\otimes I_n)$ cannot be computed due to size issues. If I had the transpose of $(I_n\odot G)$ the product would have been possible and the size of $(I_n\odot G)$ would have been as expected from the first derivative I shown from the paper.

Can anyone please show me were I'm getting it wrong?

Thanks

**UPDATE**: In my example, if I use the identity $vec(ABC)=(C^T\otimes A)vec(B)$, the result of the derivative would be$$ \frac{\partial}{\partial vec(X)}(vec(GXb)) = \frac{\partial}{\partial vec(X)}(b^t\otimes G)vec(X)=(b^t\otimes G)$$ and considering that $X$ is diagonal, we can change to a Khatri-Rao product leading to $(b^T\odot G)$.In my application, I need to get $G$ out as a separate matrix, thus the preference for the original answer's formulation. After some workarounds, I found out that the answer using my original formulation should be $$ GP^T(b\otimes I_n)$$ where $P = [e_1,e_{n+2},e_{2n+3} ... e_{n^2}] \in \mathbb{R}^{n^2,n}$ and $e_k \in \mathbb{R}^{n^2,1}$ is a column vector with unity element at position $k$. Computing the results will show that $$ GP^T(b\otimes I_n)=(b^T\odot G)$$
The problem still remains that I cannot manage to show that $$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(A(x))=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(GX) = GP^T \in \mathbb{R}^{n,n^{2}}$$ which make sense size-wise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\vecc#1{\operatorname{vec}\LR{#1}}
\def\grad#1#2{\frac{\partial #1}{\partial #2}}
\def\m#1{\left[\begin{array}{c}#1\end{array}\right]}
\def\v#1{{\bf{#1}}}
$The linked paper is terrible.
It defines the gradient in terms of the Kronecker product as
$$\grad{A}{x} \;=\; \LR{A\otimes\grad{}{x^T}}$$
This introduces either the *insane* convention of having the differential operator acting on the variable to its **left** or else a re-definition of the Kronecker product.

Here is a much [better paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0024379504001296)
which covers integration as well as differentiation.  It utilizes MacRae's (1974) definition, which in terms of the **standard** Kronecker product (and a differential operator acting on the variable to its **right**) is
$$\grad{A}{x} \;=\; \LR{\grad{}{x}\otimes A}$$
Magnus and Neudecker recommend vectorizing all matrices, leading to the simple convention
$$\grad{A}{x} \;\to\; {\grad{\vecc{A}}{x^T}}$$
However, the best approach is probably plain old index notation
$$\LR{\grad{A}{x}}_{ijk} \;=\; \grad{A_{ij}}{x_k}$$
Unless Kang's notation is widespread in your particular field of study, I would recommend reading papers by other researchers. Seriously, *any* journal article by *any* author will be better than this paper.

### Update

Just to be clear, here are the standard Kronecker products between a matrix and a vector
$$\eqalign{
{\v{A}}\otimes{\v{x}}
 &= \m{
a_{11}\v{x} &\ldots &a_{1p}\v{x} \\
\vdots &\ddots &\vdots \\
a_{m1}\v{x} &\ldots &a_{mp}\v{x} \\
}
\qquad\quad
\v{x}\otimes\v{A} &= \m{x_1\v{A} \\ \vdots \\ x_n\v{A}} \\
}$$
Notice how the left factor is expanded *before* the right factor.

Now here is MacRae's definition of a matrix-by-vector gradient
$$\eqalign{
\grad{\v{A}}{\v{x}}
 &= \m{\grad{\v{A}}{x_1} \\ \vdots \\ \grad{\v{A}}{x_n}}
 \;\equiv\; \LR{\grad{}{\v{x}}\otimes \v{A}} \\
}$$

and here is equation (8) from Khang's paper
$$\eqalign{
\grad{\v{A}}{\v{x}} &= \m{
\grad{a_{11}}{\v{x}} &\grad{a_{12}}{\v{x}} &\ldots &\grad{a_{1p}}{\v{x}} \\
\grad{a_{21}}{\v{x}} &\grad{a_{22}}{\v{x}} &\ldots &\grad{a_{2p}}{\v{x}} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
\grad{a_{m1}}{\v{x}} &\grad{a_{m2}}{\v{x}} &\ldots &\grad{a_{mp}}{\v{x}} \\
}
 \;\overset{?}{=}\; \LR{\v{A}\otimes\grad{}{\v{x^T}}} \\
}$$
The Kronecker product (unlike the matrix product) isn't reordered when transposed
$$\LR{A\otimes B}^T
 \;=\; \LR{A^T\otimes B^T}
 \;\ne\; \LR{B^T\otimes A^T}$$
so my objection is not simply about the **layout convention**, which involves transposing the gradient as a whole, i.e.
$$\LR{\grad{y}{x}} \quad-{\rm vs}-\quad \LR{\grad{y}{x}}^T$$
but rather the *fundamental* behavior of differential operators and Kronecker products.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If I'm getting this correctly, your comment is mainly related to the layout used. In my field, the numerator layout (or Jacobian) layout is used. Thus for example $\frac{\partial Ax}{\partial x}=A$ and $\frac{\partial x^TAx}{\partial x}=x^T(A+A^T)$. Isn't this the convention used in the paper I shown?

Comment: Update: After going through some element by element derivation (using your suggested vectorization notation), I realized that the derivative shown in the paper I shown does not indeed conform with the Jacobian. If it did, the result should have the number of columns equal to the number of elements in vector w.r.t which it was derived, ie, the result of $\frac{\partial A(x)}{\partial x}$ should have the number of columns equal to the size of $x$ (or am I still confusing?)

Comment: Thanks for the update. After some more thought and work, I found that Magnus and Neudecker recommendation of vectorizing the matrix works best for me. This is because it maintains the Jacobian formulation, which I need as I'm using  these results for state space systems linearization.

Answer (score 0):

Let
$\mathbf{A}=\mathbf{G}\mathrm{diag}(\mathbf{x})$

It follows
$\mathbf{a}
=\mathrm{vec}(\mathbf{A})
=(\mathbf{I}_n\odot\mathbf{G})\mathbf{x}$

The Jacobian is simply
$\mathbf{I}_n\odot\mathbf{G}$
with dimensions $n^2 \times n$.
Here $\odot$ is the Khatri-Rao product.